# How do I extract substring from this line using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String line:
`dn: cn=Customer Management,ou=groups,dc=digitalglobe,dc=com`

I want to extract just this from the line above:  `Customer Management`

I've tried the following RegEx expression but it does quite do what I want:

```
^dn: cn=(.*?),
```

Here is the java code snippet that tests the above expression:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^dn: cn=(.*?),");
String mydata = "dn: cn=Delivery Admin,ou=groups,dc=digitalglobe,dc=com";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("No match found!");
}
```

The output is "No match found"... :(

Comment: Your regex should work. In what way does it not do what you want?

Comment: You can use a lookbehind (`(?<=^dn: cn=)[^,]+`) or more simply stick with your current regex (or the somewhat more efficient `^dn: cn=([^,]+)`) but retrieve your information from its first capturing group, however it might be worth using a DN parser

Comment: @Aaron - I tried your look behind expression with the code above also... it still gets not found... your expression works perfectly in regexpal.com but not in my silly java code.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should work properly, but `matches` attempts to match the regex to the *entire* string. Instead, use the `find` method which will look for a match at any point in the string.

```
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("No match found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the matcher want to match the *whole* input. Try adding a wildcard to the end of the pattern.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^dn: cn=(.*?),.*");
String mydata = "dn: cn=Delivery Admin,ou=groups,dc=digitalglobe,dc=com";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("No match found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

@NOTE: instead of using matches you have to use find

public static void main(String[] args)
  {

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^dn: cn=(.*?),");
String mydata = "dn: cn=Delivery Admin,ou=groups,dc=digitalglobe,dc=com";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("No match found!");
}
```

}